# split a word using HXT

Tags: haskell, split, hxt

I would like to know, how am i able to split a word with HXT ?
For example :

I have that ->

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import System.Environment  --para uso do getArgs

data Class = Class { name ::String }
    deriving (Show,Eq)

main = do
   [src]<- getArgs
   teams <- runX(readDocument [ withValidate no] src  >>> getClass)
   print teams

atTag tag = deep (isElem >>> hasName tag)
getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- getAttrValue "rdf:about" -< l
    returnA -< Class { name = className }
```

And i want to split the word ClassName !
Because the result of that programs (teams), gives me a set of hyperlink website (http:// ......) ! (Due to the XML file )
Can anyone give me some hints to solve it, please ?
Thank you !

Comment: Do you want to split the String, which is stored in the variable ``className``? If this is the case, how do you want to split it? Can you provide a (short) sample XML and the result, you want to have in the end?

Comment: Example:
http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Window
i want the "Window" !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [splitOn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v%3asplitOn) of the package [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split):

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import Text.XML.HXT.Core
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)

...

getClass = atTag "owl:Class" >>>
    proc l -> do
    className <- getAttrValue "rdf:about" -< l
    returnA -< Class { name = splitOn "#" className !! 1 }
```

Example in ghci:

```
> import Data.List.Split
> let className = "http://www.xfront.com/owl/ontologies/camera/#Window"
> splitOn "#" className !! 1
Loading package split-0.2.2 ... linking ... done.
"Window"
```

The above code just works, if there is just one "#" in all of your URLs. If they are more complex, you shall have a look an the package [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec).

Comment: i don't have the package Data.List ! 
And cannot update cabal ! Is it normal ?

Comment: You need the module ``Data.List.Split`` (not ``Data.List``) which you get by installing ``split`` (i.e. ``cabal install split``)

Comment: The command ``cabal update`` should work and also installing ``split`` shouldn't be a problem. If this is the case for you, you should maybe ask a new question here providing with a detailed description of your error and posting your error messages...